# Clean multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I struggle to clean a multidimensional array. I find several Q&A:s on this topic but yet I can't get it to work.

The array $overPayments comes out (from a db call) as below.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [invoiceID] => 103080 
        [invoiceNumber] => 781 
        [faktBel] => 1500.00 
        [totalPayed] => 1500.00
        [sumPayedOnThisJournal] => 1500.00 
        [totOPtoday] => 0.00 
        [totOPbeforeToday] => -1500.00 
        [totOPthisJournal] => 0.00 ) 
    [1] => Array( 
        [invoiceID] => 103290 
        [invoiceNumber] => 7818 
        [faktBel] => 648.00 
        [totalPayed] => 893.00 
        [sumPayedOnThisJournal] => 893.00
        [totOPtoday] => 245.00 
        [totOPbeforeToday] => -648.00 
        [totOPthisJournal] => 245.00 ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [invoiceID] => 103453
        [invoiceNumber] => 202071
        [faktBel] => 2250.00 
        [totalPayed] => 2317.00 
        [sumPayedOnThisJournal] => 2317.00 
        [totOPtoday] =>67.00 
        [totOPbeforeToday] => -2250.00 
        [totOPthisJournal] => 67.00 )
)
```

What I need to do is loop through the array called $overPayments containing about 200 sub arrays, and remove all "rows" (subarrays) that have $overPayment['totOPthisJournal'] <= 0. So that I end up with a either modified or new multidimensional array where the totOPthisJournal value is > 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is what you are after.

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($overPayments, function($value) {
    return $value['totOPthisJournal'] > 0;
});
```

Comment: This works nicely as well. array_filter was the function I was trying to use but never managed. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Put this **[array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)** into a **[foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)** loop:

```
foreach($overPayments as $key => $value) {
    if($value['totOPthisJournal'] <= 0) {
        $key = null;
    }
}
```

This removes the overPayment where `[totOPthisJournal] <= 0`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah doing this in the query would have been better but overPayments is not a field but an alias that is created based on a quite complex logic in the query so that is not really an option. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

just try to unset the array index for which 'totOPthisJournal' is <=0

```
<?php
$array = Array ( '0' => Array ( 'invoiceID' => 103080, 'invoiceNumber' => 781, 'faktBel' => 1500.00, 
        'totalPayed' => 1500.00,'sumPayedOnThisJournal' => 1500.00, 'totOPtoday' => 0.00, 
        'totOPbeforeToday' => -1500.00, 'totOPthisJournal' => 0.00 ), '1' => Array( 'invoiceID' => 103290,
                 'invoiceNumber' => 7818, 'faktBel' => 648.00, 'totalPayed' => 893.00,
                 'sumPayedOnThisJournal' => 893.00,'totOPtoday' => 245.00, 'totOPbeforeToday' => -648.00,
                 'totOPthisJournal' => 245.00 ), '2' => Array ( 'invoiceID' => 103453,'invoiceNumber' => 202071,
                        'faktBel' => 2250.00, 'totalPayed' => 2317.00, 'sumPayedOnThisJournal' => 2317.00, 
                        'totOPtoday' =>67.00, 'totOPbeforeToday' => -2250.00, 'totOPthisJournal' => 67.00)); 

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if($array[$key]['totOPthisJournal'] <= 0){
        unset($array[$key]);
    }

}

print_r($array);
```